# Cannot find a getter for <... app:myValue> that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a `View` (not `ViewModel`!) with some more complex logic/state for which I want to enable two way databinding. So instead of using static BindingAdapters, I wanted to use getters/setters.

Therefore I did the following:

```
var myValue: String = ""
@Bindable get(): String {
    return field
}
set(value: String) {
    field=value // this creates backing field
    setText(value)
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.myValue)
}
```

When compiling this (with `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` to get the details) I get this error:

```
Caused by: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding error(s):

ERROR: Cannot find a getter for <com.example.test.MyAutoCompleteTextView app:myValue> 
that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'

If a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly
and that the parameter type matches. 
file:///Users/myuser/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_my.xml Line:123
```

The part I don't really understand is

```
ERROR: Cannot find a getter for <com.example.test.MyAutoCompleteTextView app:myValue> 
that accepts parameter type 'java.lang.String'
```

Why does it look for a getter with a parameter of type String? The getter should **return** a string, but not have a String **parameter**?

Comment: Not that it necessarily answers your question but I think that can just be get() = field

Comment: Does it work when you explicitely declare a `getMyValue()` method?

Comment: I tried that too, but unfortunately no ):

Comment: Maybe this will help along? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_objects I haven't quite figured out how all this bindable stuff works

Comment: thanks, I already read this, but couldn't find anything on it, that explains my problem ):

Comment: emm..where is this "field" variable? i can see only myValue and yes, for this there is no getter method

Comment: getMyValue() and setMyValue() ?

Comment: also tried explicitely writing that, didn't change anything